# HashMap keys return null when the map demonstrably contains them

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I'm currently trying to solve a code wars problem titled *Battle ships: Sunk damaged or not touched?*. Given a 2D array containing 'ships' and another 2D array containing the attack coordinates I have to generate a score. I populate a hashmap with the ship locations and then check the attack locations against the map. When printed, the original locations and attacks are identical on the first test case. Despite this, `map.get()` continues to return *null* and `map.containsKey()` returns *false*.

```
public class BattleshipsSDN {
public static Map<String,Double> damagedOrSunk(final int[][] board, final int[][] attacks) {

    int y;
    HashMap<int[], Integer> ships = new HashMap<>();

    // build map of boat locations
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        y = board.length - i;
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) continue;
            else {
                int[] location = {j+1,y};
                ships.put(location, board[i][j]);
                System.out.println("Location: "+location[0]+","+location[1]);
                //System.out.println("Value: "+ships.get(location));
            }
        }
    }

    //establish original boat lengths
    int ship1 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 1);
    int ship2 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 2);
    int ship3 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 3);
    System.out.println("Ships: "+ship1+ship2+ship3);

    for(int[] x : ships.keySet()) System.out.println(x[0]+","+x[1]);

    //check for hits
    for (int[] x : attacks) {
        System.out.println(x[0]+","+x[1]);
        if (ships.get(x) == null) continue;
        else{
            System.out.println("Hit");
            ships.remove(x);
        }
    }

    double sunk = 0;
    double hit = 0;
    double missed = 0;

    //find number of ship spots after attacks
    int leftShip1 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 1);
    int leftShip2 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 2);
    int leftShip3 = Collections.frequency(new ArrayList<Integer>(ships.values()), 3);
    System.out.println("Ships: "+leftShip1);

    if (ship1 > 0) {
        if (leftShip1 == 0) sunk++;
        else if (ship1 % leftShip1 > 0) hit++;
        else if (ship1 == leftShip1) missed++;
    }
    if (ship2 > 0) {
        if (leftShip2 == 0) sunk++;
        else if (ship2 % leftShip2 > 0) hit++;
        else if (ship2 == leftShip2) missed++;
    }
    if (ship3 > 0) {
        if (leftShip3 == 0) sunk++;
        else if (ship3 % leftShip3 > 0) hit ++;
        else if (ship3 == leftShip3) missed++;
    }
    HashMap<String, Double> score = new HashMap<>();
    score.put("sunk", sunk);
    score.put("damaged", hit);
    score.put("notTouched", missed);
    score.put("points", sunk + hit/2 - missed);
    return score;

}
```

}

I'm not asking you to solve the problem for me. I'm just completely stumped as to why my HashMap is acting this way. Which likely means it's some really small stupid thing.

**Note:** The *y* values of the locations are flipped because in the problems 'board' the y-coord is measured from the bottom. So in a 4x4 board or array the index [0][0] corresponds to the coordinates (1,4)

Comment: `int[]s` don't override `equals` and `hashCode`; they compare by identity.

Comment: Goes for arrays in general.  Arrays as keys in maps don't work.  Try another data structure.

Comment: For the love of `<your favourite deity>` use collections in preference to arrays. If you change to using `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]` your problem will vanish.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

The problem is that you are using `int[]` as key for your `HashMap`. Arrays don't override the methods `equals` and `hashCode`. Thus those methods, for them, compares objects by their **identity** instead of their **content**.

Consider this:

```
int[] first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] second = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

System.out.println(first.equals(second)); // Prints 'false'
```

Both arrays have **the same content** but they are considered **not equal** since they are different objects (`first != second`).

When you now call something like `map.get(key)` the map **searches for the key** by using its **hash-code**, the one returned by the `hashCode` method. However this method also works on an **identity-base** for arrays.

If you now store the data with a key and later re-create a key with the same content, in order to fetch the data, you will not find it anymore:

```
Map<int[], String> map = new HashMap<>();

// Put data
int[] key = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
map.put(key, "test");

// Retrieve it
int[] similarKey = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
String data = map.get(similarKey); // Is 'null', not ' test'

// Try it with 'key' instead of 'similarKey'
String otherData = map.get(key); // Works now since same object
```

Though `similarKey` has the same content, it has a different `hashCode` since it is **not the same object** (by identity).

---

### Solution

To solve the issue simply use a data-structure which implements `hashCode` and `equals` not per identity but per **comparing the content**. You may use stuff from `Collection` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)), an `ArrayList` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) for example:

```
Map<List<Integer>, String> map = new HashMap<>();

// Put data
int[] key = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> keyAsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(key));
map.put(keyAsList, "test");

// Retrieve it
int[] similarKey = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> similarKeyAsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(similarKey));
String data = map.get(similarKeyAsList); // Is 'test' now
```

Comment: It's practically always preferable to define variables as their most abstract type, ie `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`. See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: That is correct. I avoided that to keep it simple. However if you want to substitute `int[]` by a `List` it may be preferable to enforce `ArrayList` such that everyone knows **index-based access** works fast, but that's just a side-note for OP.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer that for me. After realizing its an issue with using an object as a hash key there's definitely duplicate questions like this one.

Comment: @DillanShmog Your welcome. That's fine, especially if you don't know what the problem is. I mean, how should you search for something that you don't know.